# How to use a template service to reduce HTML?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular-directive

I have a component that wraps form controls. This adds reusable code for each control, but for simplicity, lets say all it does is add a label:

app.component:

```
<app-wrapper labelText="First Name">
  <input type="text" >
</app-wrapper>
```

wrapper.component:

```
<div style="border:thin solid; padding:10px">
    <label>{{labelText}}</label>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>

export class WrapperComponent {
    @Input() labelText;
}
```

I'd like to make the wrapper a @Directive instead, so that the amount of HTML in the form is further reduced, but I can't quite get my head around it on how it would work. My thoughts are something like this:

app.component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `

  <input type="text" wrapper labelText="First Name">
  <input type="text" wrapper labelText="Last Name" >

  <ng-template #tpl>
    <div style="border:thin solid; padding:10px">
        <label>{{labelText}}</label>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  </ng-template>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('tpl', {read:TemplateRef}) tpl
  constructor(private service: TemplateService) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.service.template = this.tpl;
  }
}
```

wrapper.dir

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[wrapper]'
})
export class WrapperDirective {
    @Input('labelText') labelText;

  constructor(
    private vc:ViewContainerRef,
    private service:TemplateService) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    of(null).pipe(
      delay(1)).subscribe(() => {
        let tpl = this.service.template;
        this.vc.createEmbeddedView(this.service.template)
      })
  }

}
```

Unfortunately i believe this puts the label after the input tag instead of in front. How can I insert it in front?

The other issue is: how do I access the #labelText in the template?

Comment: added an example with a structural directive in my comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/wrapper-directive?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a component with an attribute selector that you can set on the div that wraps the input. Something like:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'div[wrapper]',
  template: `
    <label>{{labelText}}</label>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `,
  styles: [`
  :host {
    border:thin solid; 
    padding:10px;
  }
  `]
})
export class WrapperComponent {
  @Input() labelText: string;
}
```

and use it like:

```
<div wrapper [labelText]="'test text'">
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/attribute-selector-component?file=src%2Fapp%2Fwrapper.component.ts

Accessing the `labelText` in the template is pretty simple. You just need to pass a context (2nd parameter) to `createEmbeddedView` (`{labelText: this.labelText}`). You can also insert the template as the first child of the view by passing the index (3rd param) to `createEmbeddedView` as 0.

https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createEmbeddedView

If you really want to use a directive, it has to be a structural directive if you want to change the element position in the DOM (add a wrapper around it). This way you actually get a template of the element and a template for the wrapper and your directive wraps them around (of course you can also use a template service if you want...):

```
import { Directive, Input, ViewContainerRef, TemplateRef, EmbeddedViewRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[wrapperLabelText]',
})
export class WrapperDirective {
  private _labelText: string;
  private embedded: EmbeddedViewRef<any>;

  @Input('wrapperLabelText')
  get labelText() {
    return this._labelText;
  }
  set labelText(value: string) {
    this._labelText = value;
    if (this.embedded) {
      this.embedded.context.labelText = value;
    }
  };

  @Input('wrapperLabelTextWrapper')
  wrapperTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private vc: ViewContainerRef,
  ) {

  }

  async ngAfterViewInit() {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve));
    const ref = this.vc.createEmbeddedView(this.wrapperTemplate, {
      wrapped: this.templateRef,
      labelText: this.labelText,
    });
  }
}
```

and use it like:

```
<input type="text" *wrapperLabelText="'test';wrapper:wrapperTemplate">
<input type="text" *wrapperLabelText="'test 2';wrapper:wrapperTemplate">

<ng-template #wrapperTemplate let-wrapped="wrapped" let-labelText="labelText">
  <div style="border:thin solid; padding:10px">
    <label>{{labelText}}</label>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="wrapped"></ng-container>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/wrapper-directive?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: My thinking was that the HTML would be less cluttery if i use a directive instead of wrapping each control in a component tag - but i think you've changed my mind. More straightforward and more flexible. thanks!